# have this xml data and how to get this sql server table

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql, xpath

I have this xml data and how to get this sql server table

```
 DECLARE @Xml XMl=
 '<MappingList>
   <Mapping>
      <ManufactorID>1</ManufactorID>
      <ManufactorID>2</ManufactorID>
   </Mapping>
   <PageInfo>
      <pageSize>10</pageSize>
      <pageIndex>2</pageIndex>
   </PageInfo>
</MappingList>'
```

I want to get the table like below：

```
(ID  Size  Inx)

(1    10    2)

(2    10    2)
```

Comment: Hi Tommy! As you are new here (Btw: Welcome!) please allow me one hint: It would be very kind of you to tick the acceptance check below the (best) answer's vote counter. This will 1) mark this issue as solved 2) make it easier for followers to find the best solution 3) pay points to the answerer and 4) pay points to you. Once you've crossed the 15 points border yourself, you are  - additionally - asked to vote on contributions. This is the SO-way to say thank you. Happy Coding!

Answer (score 1):

I doubt, that the internal structure of your XML is the best you could find...

But nevertheless you might query this like follows:

```
DECLARE @Xml XMl=
 '<MappingList>
   <Mapping>
      <ManufactorID>1</ManufactorID>
      <ManufactorID>2</ManufactorID>
   </Mapping>
   <PageInfo>
      <pageSize>10</pageSize>
      <pageIndex>2</pageIndex>
   </PageInfo>
</MappingList>' 

SELECT manu.value('.','int') AS ManufactorID
      ,@xml.value('(/MappingList/PageInfo/pageSize)[1]','int') AS PageSize
      ,@xml.value('(/MappingList/PageInfo/pageIndex)[1]','int') AS PageIndex
FROM @xml.nodes('/MappingList/Mapping/ManufactorID') AS A(manu)
```

Comment: Thank u, Just as I thought and I wander what's the different between your code "  manu.value('.','int')  ” and  " manu.value('(./text())[1]','int') "  ?

Comment: @TommyWhite, well, actually there is: The first is shorter easier to parse and - uhm - lazy. Your suggestion is **much better* if you cannot predict the structure. Try this `DECLARE @x XML='<x>hallo1<a>testa</a>hallo2<b>testb</b>hallo3</x>';

SELECT x.value('.','nvarchar(max)')
      ,x.value('(./text())[1]','nvarchar(max)')
FROM @x.nodes('/x') AS A(x)
`

Comment: Thank u for your help I think I got it ! BTW : What is the second method '[1]'  meaning? The Index ? If so how to separate the serial number ? by  sub-nodes?